# Migrate local timezone dates into new Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

I am migrating a Perl-based web application to Rails. The old application stores dates in a MySql database in local (Pacific) time. For example, there is a `created` field that might have the value `06/06/2008 14:00:00` representing 2:00 PM June 6, 2008 (PDT) whereas `02/02/2002 06:30:00` represents 6:00 AM February 2, 2002 (PST).

I have written a rake task to take all the old data and import it into the new database. The date in the new database still *looks* like `06/06/2008 14:00:00` but, of course, my Rails application interprets this as UTC.

The migrating task looks like this:

```
# Migrating old events in Perl application to new events in Rails
oldevents = OldEvent.all
oldevents.each do |oldevent|
  newevent = Event.convert_old_event_to_newevent(oldevent)
  newevent.save!
end
```

The interesting code is in the static method `Event.convert_old_event_to_newevent`:

```
def Event.convert_old_event_to_newevent(oldevent)
  ...
  # If the "created" field in the old db contains '06/06/2008 14:00:00' (meaning
  # 2:00 PM PDT (since June is during daylight savings time) then the  
  # "created_at" field in the new database will contain the same string which
  # Rails interprets as 2:00 PM GMT.
  newevent.created_at = oldevent.created 
  ...
  return newevent
end
```

So, in the migration process, before storing the dates in the new database I need to read the date/times from the old database, convert them to UTC, and then store that in the new database.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> Time.local(*'06/06/2008 14:00:00'.split(/[:\/ ]/).values_at(2,0,1,3..5)).utc
=> Fri Jun 06 21:00:00 UTC 2008
```

This obviously returns a Ruby core library `Time` object that can be formatted any way you like.

If your time zone is not already Pacific, run your rake import task like:

```
$ TZ=PST rake initdb:import # whatever
```

Now, Rails defines a type called DateTime which you may need, and it wants real integer parameters, so:

```
DateTime.civil_from_format :local, *'06/06/2008 14:00:00'.split(/[:\/ ]/).map(&:to_i).values_at(2,0,1,3..5)
```

Comment: Are you sure the line `TZ=PST rake initdb:import` would work? Remember, the dates and times in the old database occur throughout the year during both daylight and non-daylight savings time. Isn't PST just non-daylight savings time?

Comment: If you are worried about that then just say **TZ=PST8PDT ruby** *blah blah* but I'm pretty sure **PST** is an alias for **PST8PDT** already.